# Why is there a vertical asymptote at x = 3 but g(x) does not have a vertical asymptote at x = 3?

Tags: calculus, limits

The question was an explanation for why $f(x)$ has a vertical asymptote at $x = 3$, but $g(x)$ does not. Mention limits within the answer.

Perhaps I'm solving them wrong but it looks like there is an asymptote in both. Also I would imagine that limits come into play because the values approach the asymptote at $x = 3$

$$f(x) = \frac{x^2 - 7x + 4}{4x^2 - 4x - 24}$$

$$g(x) = \frac{-2x^2 + 12x - 18}{4x^2 - 8x - 12}$$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Hint:** Factor everything, and look for any $(x - 3)$ factors. If such a factor is found in both the numerator and denominator so that they cancel, then the limit as $x \to 3$ exists so that the discontinuity at $x = 3$ is a hole, not an asymptote. Otherwise, if the $(x - 3)$ factor is in the denominator but not the numerator, then the discontinuity must indeed be a vertical asymptote.

Comment: Thank you very much. This is a very helpful answer! When I solved it, there looked to be a vertical asymptote in both f(x) and g(x) so I'm not sure how g(x) doesn't have the asymptote at x=3.

Comment: What did you get when you factored everything in $g(x)$? Did any $(x - 3)$ factors cancel?

Comment: The same as the answer below this. g(x) = -1/2 ((x-3)^2) / (x+3)(x+1)

Comment: You should have gotten:
$$
g(x) = \frac{-2(x^2 - 6x + 9)}{4(x^2 - 2x - 3)} = \frac{-(x - 3)^2}{2(x + 1)(x - 3)}
$$

Comment: Oh okay, so then the (x-3)'s can cancel so g(x) would not have the vertical asymptote?

Comment: That's correct. $\lim_{x \to 3} g(x) = 0$, so it's a hole.

Comment: Great, thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

we have
$f(x)=\frac{x^2-7x+4}{4(x-3)(x+2)}$
and
$g(x)=-\frac{1}{2}\frac{(x-3)^2}{(x+3)(x+1)}$